# How to control user distribution when I have multiple user classes?

Tags: locust

In my locust file I have multiple user classes something like below and when I run tests Locust splitting load automatically, but I want to run Simple1 with 80% of the load and Simple2 with remaining 20% load.

How can I achieve this behavior?

is there any way similar to task weight sort of thing for user classes?

```
class Simple1(HttpUser):
    host = "http://localhost:8080"
    tasks = [Simple1Taskset]


class Simple2(HttpUser):
    host = "http://localhost:8080"
    tasks = [Simple2Taskset]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is to use [weights](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#weight-attribute). You can put a weight attribute `weight = 8` in Simple1 and `weight = 2` in Simple2. Alternatively, if you use the `@task` decorator on your functions you can weight individual tasks and not the users via `@task(8)` and `@task(2)`.